# TFS: Cloaking multiple elements from command line

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tf-cli, cloaking

Suppose we have a folder `$/myProject/myFolder` on the TFS server which contains some files and sub-folders.

Is there any possibility to iteratively cloak every element under this folder (not recursively) using the `tf.exe` command line utility?

I can't simply cloak the root folder `$/myProject/myFolder` because I need to decloak some of its elements afterwards which seems only to be possible, if each element has been cloaked independently.

In the end, I want to achieve that all elements below a specific root folder are cloaked except of some predefined ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing to the worst pieces of source code I have ever written, this one is definitely under the top three.

However, after doing almost every possible batch beginner's mistake, the code below finally does what I need (considering the limitation mentioned in the code).

It will cloak all folders and files below the predefinded root folder `myServerFolder`. `myServerFolder` must have the following syntax including the final slash: `$/myProject/myFolder/`.

If anyone has a good idea to simplify the code or has found a bug please edit it directly or let me know.

Again, thank you for your support!

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Limitation: Folder and file names must not end with ")" nor start with "$"
set myServerFolder=$/myProject/myFolder/

REM Process Folders
for /f "Tokens=*" %%a in ('tf.exe dir %myServerFolder%') do (SET TEXT=%%a& SET SUBSTR_A=!TEXT:~-1!& SET SUBSTR_B=!TEXT:~0,1!& (IF "!SUBSTR_A!" NEQ ":" IF "!SUBSTR_A!" NEQ ")" (IF "!SUBSTR_B!" EQU "$" (set currParam=!TEXT:~1!&(tf.exe workfold /cloak "%myServerFolder%%!currParam!")))))

REM Process Files
for /f "Tokens=*" %%a in ('tf.exe dir %myServerFolder%') do (SET TEXT=%%a& SET SUBSTR_A=!TEXT:~-1!& SET SUBSTR_B=!TEXT:~0,1!& (IF "!SUBSTR_A!" NEQ ":" IF "!SUBSTR_A!" NEQ ")" (IF "!SUBSTR_B!" NEQ "$" (set currParam=!TEXT!&(tf.exe workfold /cloak "%myServerFolder%%!currParam!")))))

PAUSE
```

Comment: I proposed a possible solution. Feel free to comment.

Comment: I'd wrap it in powershell just to be able to forget these for constructs and variable manipulation syntax messes s in batch files ;)

Answer (score 2):

With some creative Batch processing, you can probably combine `tf dir .` and `tf workfold /cloak`. But there is no standard way to chain these command together without parsing the output from `tf dir`.

It's probably easier to do with Powershell and the TFS client object model. Use the static [`Workstation.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workstation.current(v=vs.120).aspx) property to find the connection settings [`Workstation.GetWorkspaceInfo(path) .ServerUri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspaceinfo.serveruri(v=vs.120).aspx), from there use the [`VersionControlServer.GetWorkspace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138954(v=vs.120).aspx) method, to grab the workspace and then call the [`Workspace.Cloak`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.cloak(v=vs.120).aspx) method to cloak the items you found using [`VersionControlServer.GetItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138913(v=vs.120).aspx) method.

An example that comes quite close can be found here:

- https://github.com/mmessano/PowerShell/blob/master/TFSCheckIn.ps1

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. Please find my proposed solution below.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, it's safe and easy:

```bsh
    PS> $folders = Get-ChildItem
    # filter $folders as needed 
    PS> $folders | ForEach-Object { tf workfold /cloak $_.Name }
```